# How can I use a class variable in its defined functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a class object and I want to define a global variable for it, so that the functions defined within this `class` can use it. This variable is not actually variable it's just a value that I'll use in the functions.

So far I've tried what's shown below and it works but I'd like the value to be exclusive for the `class`.

```py
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
key = 30


class Caesar:
    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self.phrase = phrase.casefold()

    def encrypt(self):
        y2 = ""
        for ltr in self.phrase:
            if ltr in alpha:
                cntr = alpha.index(ltr)
                if (cntr + key) > 25:
                    module = (cntr + key) % (len(alpha))
                    if (cntr + module) > 25:
                        foo = cntr - module
                        y2 += alpha[cntr - foo]
                    else:
                        y2 += alpha[module]
                else:
                    y2 += alpha[cntr + key]
            else:
                y2 += " "
        return y2
```

What I'd like to do is to place the alpha variable inside the `class`, and well, the key variable I'd like it to be variable as well but with a default value, of course being available for the `encrypt()` function.

Comment: Would a [class attribute](https://dzone.com/articles/python-class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes) work for you?

Comment: Right on the money there @Nakor. +1 for your helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put those declarations inside the class, and then refer to them later by using the class as a namespace:

```
class Caesar:
    alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    key = 30

    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self.phrase = phrase.casefold()

    def encrypt(self):
        alpha = Caesar.alpha
        key = Caesar.key

        y2 = ""
        for ltr in self.phrase:
            if ltr in alpha:
                cntr = index(ltr)
                if (cntr + key) > 25:
                    module = (cntr + key) % (len(alpha))
                    if (cntr + module) > 25:
                        foo = cntr - module
                        y2 += alpha[cntr - foo]
                    else:
                        y2 += alpha[module]
                else:
                    y2 += alpha[cntr + key]
            else:
                y2 += " "
        return y2
```

You could also just keep your original code and replace each instance of `alpha` with `Caesar.alpha` (and do the same for `key`), but doing that just once at the beginning of the method is more clear, in my opinion.

If you wanted to implement polymorphism (that is, you wanted to make subclasses of `Caesar` that might use different values for `alpha` or `key`), then you might instead consider using `self.__class__` to obtain the values of `alpha` and `key`, instead of using the name `Caesar` explicitly:

```
    def encrypt(self):
        alpha = self.__class__.alpha
        key = self.__class__.key
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you do not need any class nor an alphabet for that. You can use a simple function with a default value `key=30` and use the integer representation of characters, i.g `ord('a')=97` and `ord('z')=122`. You can use the `casefold` inside the function, then you could see if the letters are in the interval of the alphabet by comparing them with `'a'` and `'z'`. Finally, the module works the same, but the indexes goes from 97-122 instead of 0-25.

```
def encrypt(phrase,key=30):
    encrypted = ""
    for ltr in phrase.casefold():
        if ltr > 'a' and ltr < 'z':
            module = (ord(ltr)+key) %26
            new_ltr = chr(ord('a')+module)
        else:
            new_ltr = " "
        encrypted +=new_ltr
    return encrypted
print(encrypt("Here''s a test"))
#Output:'ebob  p   qbpq'
```

Comment: The class also comes with a decryption function, that's why I chose to create and object to contain these two functions. But the ord() function really helps, thanks :)